# How do you use a Typescript Unit Test to test Typescript in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, typescript

I'm trying to write a unit test in Typescript to test a Typescript class, but when the test is run, it doesn't know anything about the class.

I'm using Typescript (1.4) with Node Tools for Visual Studio (2013) and the test helpfully appears in Test Explorer.  When run it fails with "Reference Error: ClassC not defined."

The class I'm testing:

```
class ClassC {
    functionF() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Generated Javascript:

```
var ClassC = (function () {
    function ClassC() {
    }
    ClassC.prototype.functionF = function () {
        return 42;
    };
    return ClassC;
})();
//# sourceMappingURL=ClassC.js.map
```

The test (created from template Add -> new Item... -> TypeScript UnitTest file):

```
/// <reference path="ClassC.ts" />

import assert = require('assert');

export function classCTest() {
    var foo: ClassC = new ClassC();

    var result: number = foo.functionF();
    assert.equal(result, 42);
}
```

Generated Javascript:

```
var assert = require('assert');
function classCTest() {
    var foo = new ClassC();
    var result = foo.functionF();
    assert.equal(result, 42);
}
exports.classCTest = classCTest;
//# sourceMappingURL=ClassC_tests.js.map
```

When looking at the generated Javascript for the test it becomes obvious why the error occurs.  It does not contain the necessary definition for `ClassC`.  I thought including the reference path would help, but it obviously didn't.

How do I get the unit test to know about the class?

Comment: Import `ClassC` just like you do the assert class... rather than using the `///<reference...` comment. That way, it will be imported when you run the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought including the reference path would help, but it obviously didn't.

`export class ClassC` and then use an `import` statement instead of a `reference` comment. Also compile with the compiler flag `--module commonjs`.

More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1 and http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but presented me with another problem.  How do I test individual parts of my project without turning everything into its own external module?